# Django "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" however the primary key is BigAutoField

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-3.x, orm

I have a table named ReadUnit.

```
class ReadUnits(models.Model):
    ReadID = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True, null=False)
    ReadDate = models.DateField(null=False)
```

The settings.py has the following setting for accessing the database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'MyProjectDB',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'provider': 'SQLOLEDB'
        },
    }
}
```

The project was working perfect for several months. Between 30~40 records was added to the table everyday. Recently, I was sometimes facing with a 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint' Error. The code that inserts record to this table is very simple:

```
ReadUnits(ReadDate=str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))).save()
```

Nowadays it becomes awesome because every time this code runs, the error happens. So there isn't any record saved in DB for these days at all.

Comment: can you show what id do you have now in the db? like 1 or 2 examples

Comment: why are you using str() if you already defined  DateField???, you can use datetime.now().day

Comment: @Exprator The max for ReadID is now 36227. The duplicate  key values are something like 14380, 14381, 14382, ... that increases after several unsuccessful insert.

Comment: You are right. But it's not the problem. @MounaDhaouadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not a problem with Django or the ORM or the database connector. SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014 have a bug that when the instance is under memory pressure, and multiple concurrent connections request sequence values from the same sequence object, duplicate sequence values may be generated.
Microsoft has published a fix to resolve the issue here:

[FIX: Sequence object generates duplicate sequence values when SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014 is under memory pressure](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3011465/fix-sequence-object-generates-duplicate-sequence-values-when-sql-serve)